# Made a practice game but it's not reading "While" function as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, pycharm

#I want the While function to show only when the player has not written 'run' or 'Attack'. What can I do to correct this?

```
action = input("A goblin ambushes you, what do you do? ")

if action == "Run":
    print("You run and get away!")

if action == "Attack":
    print("You hit the Goblin, knocking it out!")

while action != "Attack" or "Run":
    action = input("That is not an action, what do you do? ")
```

Comment: The problem is, `action != "Attack" or "Run"` is not a valid way to check against "Attack" or "Run".  The link explains this.

Comment: That wasn't the only problem, so the link would only answer a third of his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do the trick:

```
action = input("A goblin ambushes you, what do you do? ")
while action != "Attack" and action !="Run": 
    action = input("That is not an action, what do you do? ")

if action == "Run": 
    print("You run and get away!")
elif action == "Attack": 
    print("You hit the Goblin, knocking it out!")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a huge noob in programming but this has helped me on the road to getting better and I appreciate it very much.

Comment: You are very welcome. And we all started coding the same way, so don't worry. If this answers your questions, it would be really appreciated, if you could mark the question as answered by clicking the checkbox next to my reply :)